# How to manage excel sheets in excel file using java without using 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, excel

I has a excel file with 4 excel sheets in it. Now i want to read or write to required excel sheets using java without using any third party lib.

I know i can read and write data using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream respecitvely. But i can handle the work sheets??

Comment: Andrew Thompson's remark was uncalled for. Let me just say that I do lots of Excel processing in Java using POI, and it is a very good package, available free of charge. I am not sure why you would be reluctant to use it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can'not, There is numerous way in Java for reading/writing files, but there is no built-in support for MS Office/Excel spreadsheets. http://poi.apache.org/ - is a key to victory.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to interface with data from an excel sheet from your Java application, I'd suggest to use the solutions suggested by other posters, it will save you a lot of work.

If, however, you want to be able to read excel files from Java (or any other programming language for that matter) 'just because you can' then you could take a look at [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat%28xls%29Specification.pdf) file and read the instructions on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615597.aspx) web-page. I would warn you that it would take considerably more time to implement your own API if you base it only on the file-specs that are publicly available. You might want to check out the work done by the people from the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) project to get an idea of how to approach it. Or (even better) contribute to the project. [Here](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html) you can find out how to go about doing that